# Increment value of TextBox by 1 using a loop and reflect progress on UI

Tags: vb.net

I want to make a program that will run a loop that will count up.

The problem I have is that if I write:

```
Dim Time As Integer = 1
While Time >= 0
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + 1
    Time = +1
End While
```

Then it does not update the text in `TextBox1` until the entire loop is done.

Comment: It *does* update it, but you freeze the UI so the updates cant be seen. `TextBox1.Refresh()`

Comment: Also `Time = +1` should be `Time += 1`. That being said you don't even need that as `Time` will always be 1 so the `While` loop will continue to increment. At the moment you've no way of exiting that. Consider a `For i = 0 To 10` statement where 10 is a number defined by you. Or if you really do want to increment indefinitely then use `While True`.

Comment: try something like this or use a background worker. http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/42690-egg-timer/

Comment: Oh and turn **Option Strict On**

Answer (score 0):

You Did not mention if you were using WPF or winforms, but either way I would suggest using a Timer to accomplish what you are trying to do. Timers run on a separate thread which allows the UI thread to continue to update and respond. Timers then fire their tick event on the UI thread to allow you to react and update things.

Here is a WPF example.

```
Class MainWindow

    Private _timer As New System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer()

    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()
        AddHandler _timer.Tick, AddressOf _timer_Tick

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

        _timer.Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)
        _timer.Start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub _timer_Tick(sender As Object, args As EventArgs)

        If IsNumeric(txtNumber.Text) Then
            txtNumber.Text = (CInt(txtNumber.Text) + 1).ToString()
        Else
            txtNumber.Text = "1"
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

If you are in Winforms you can use **System.Windows.Forms.Timer** for your timer works close to the same just the interval is in milliseconds vs a timespan.

Comment: How do i check if i am using WPF or Winforms? i have only been using visual studio for a few weeks...

Comment: Winforms your Window would end in .vb like Form1.vb

Comment: WPF your window would end in .xaml like MainWindow.xaml

Comment: @ØrjanMonradThornquist : That depends on how you created the project. The former is called a `WPF Application`, the latter is a `Windows Forms Application`. One of the best ways to find out is by checking the project properties. -- In the `Solution Explorer` right-click your project's node and press `Properties`. You'll then find what type you're using by looking under `Application type`. [**\[Screenshot from another Stack Overflow question\]**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsT8z.jpg)